# Making <img> responsive when within <a>tag?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I have been using the following css to make my images responsive

```
img{  
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;    
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work when the img is within an `<a>` tag ie.

```
<a href="#"><img class="fbicon" src="images/fbicon.png" alt="main"></a>
```

Why is this and what could be a way around it?
Here is the complete code - (it is responsive on the fiddle but not on the site):
https://jsfiddle.net/bLchqb9u/

Comment: Why are you using `max-width: 100%` not `width: 100%` ?

Comment: @CodeiSir To avoid upscaling small images, I guess.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Your code works great for me as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/c9sejcym/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bLchqb9u/         the complete code

Answer (score 0):

The `100%` always applies to the value of the parent element. By default `<a>`  doesn't have a `100%` width (it's would just be as big as it's content). You would have to change the behaviour, like this:

```
<a href="#" style="width:100%"><img class="fbicon" src="images/fbicon.png" alt="main"></a>
```

Demo here:

```html
<div style="width: 300px">
  <a href="#" style="max-width:100%">
    <img style="width:100%;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Gustave_Caillebotte_-_Paris_Street%3B_Rainy_Day_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg" alt="main">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the parent element. It's the containing block. Unless some code blockified the `a` element, it won't be the containing block. And `max-width` does not apply to non-replaced inline elements like `a`, so your solution does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

use `width` insted of `max-width` , find the working fiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/5n4rarrL/

Answer (score 0):

A percentage in [`max-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) is resolved with respect to the width of the containing block.

Then, the only case where your code may not work is

> If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then
>   the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

That should only happen when the width of the containing block is calculated with the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float). For example, floats, absolutely positioned or inline-blocks with `width: auto`.

```css
div {
  float: left; /* Shrink-to-fit width, depends on the content */
}
img {  
  max-width: 100%; /* Depends on the containing block */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/200/" />
  </a>
</div>
```

The solution is preventing the containing flock from depending on the content. Make sure it has an explicit width.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%; /* No longer depends on the content */
}
img {  
  max-width: 100%; /* Depends on the containing block */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/200/">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, my contained img element is absolutely positioned (as i need it to be)ie. `.fbicon{
position: absolute; 
top: 5px; left: 5px;  
 transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}`  .fbicon itself is within a relatively positioned header

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bLchqb9u/      It works in the jfiddle but doesn't seem to work on my site

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `<a>` element a `block` container.

Like this:

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
img{  
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;    
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img class="fbicon" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2_1x.png" alt="main"></a>
```

This way the `<a>` tag will behave as a container and the image will stretch to the size of that.

Answer (score 0):

Tried display and width suggestions, but still the the images were not responsive for some reason (while another img was), even though it worked on jfiddle. Finally, the new srcset came to the rescue,

```
<img class="fbicon"  src="images/fbiconlarge.png"
     srcset="images/fbiconlarge.png 1380w,
             images/fbiconlarge.png 640w,
             images/fbiconlarge.png 320w"
```

However must say, now its a bit too responsive - ending up too small on the smallest screen. Will post a separate Q. THanks @Oriol, Hasan, Hans, CodeiSir